# How to get awesome-typescript-loader experience with babel

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have a webpack project using awesome-typescript-loader. I recently switched to @babel/preset-typescript, but it only does the compilation, but doesn't typecheck before that, halting it. I tried running `tsc --watch` and `webpack-dev-server` parallelly, but then they both become independent. I also tried `tsc --watch && webpack-dev-server`, but since `tsc --watch` never exits, `webpack-dev-server` is never run.
How can I get the earlier experience of failing compilation on typecheck fail using babel and webpack?

Comment: You can run both `tsc` and `webpack-dev-server` concurrently using the `concurrent` npm module and add a script: `"concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"webpack-dev-server\""`. This should get around `tsc --watch` never exiting issue.

Comment: I already mentioned that I run them parallelly, but that makes them independent of each other